# Play Framework - lighttpd to handle SSL

Tags: ssl, playframework, lighttpd

Currently I try to improve the performance of my Play! application and i'm thinking about how to handle multiple instances (Scaleability) in future. The application should run with SSL.

Now I read: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/HTTPServer

It states:

> Note that using a front end HTTP server will rarely give you better performance than using Play server directly. **However, HTTP servers are very good at handling HTTPS**, conditional GET requests and static assets, and many services assume a front end HTTP server is part of your architecture.

Does that mean that it would be a good idea to run the Play! app just as HTTP server (not HTTPS) and put a lighthttpd in front, configured for SSL, which acts as a proxy for the Play! app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In very general *yes*, you can use frontend HTTP server for several purposes and minimize stress on your application, there's no reason to handle i.e. requests to static and **public** assets, as probably HTTP server will do it faster and/or better, that way your app will handle only traffic which is required to be handled by app.

Further, you can also use FE server as a load balancer and divide stress put on single app - to several instances even on separate machines.

Comment: My question should specifically target the SSL thingy. Can lighthttpd do it significantly faster than Play! framework. Or in other words: If one would only use lighthttpd for SSLing the backend server, would this be a good idea?

Comment: I wrote 'yes' ;) and added several other reasons, anyway must to say that I used nginx for this purpose... just don't know light